# How to select and view only a specific cell?

Tags: excel, xpath, syntax

I want to extract from the next code, only the first value. Unfortunately, I was unable and  I didn't found similar answer for my question.
So, here is the example of script:

**$1.61**

With bold I mark the value which I am interested to be visible. Only this value in one cell. Unfortunately I didn't have need the rest of values from table.

Here I will add my function (function will be use ):

=importxml("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/polygon","//td/span")

Please let me know how how to select to view only 1st line/value.

Thanks to all for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should select 1st `//td/span`

```
=importxml("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/polygon","(//td/span)[1]")
```

---

**Reference**

https://librarycarpentry.org/lc-webscraping/02-xpath/index.html

Comment: Thank you quick feedback Max ! That was MAGIC ! Icheck a ton of variants, but NOTHING, and you give this simple solution. Many-Many Thanks !!!